# Altair: change label spacing for axis with ordinal values

Tags: python, pandas, altair, vega-lite

I started with this reference point: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1576.

For which I was able to display the x-axis label like so:
[image]

I'm using `ordinal` axis formatting to display dates (in order to skip weekend dates).

I'm dynamically selecting valid dates within the dataframe's index, and yet, there are values that are not displaying on the chart.

It's not just these two missing values... certain dates just don't want to display (like `"Jan 29, 2021"`, for which both prior and subsequent dates display fine).

Any ideas why these dates aren't showing up? Is this a `datetime` parsing issue? As I'm converting from `datetime` there aren't any excess spaces in my `strftime`. If I try to display the `"Jan 29, 2021"`, it still doesn't display.

**EDIT3: Found the problem. Removed prior edits to clarify, but still don't know the solution**

This appears to be a [streamlit](https://streamlit.io) integration issue. I cannot reproduce the error when I circumvent Streamlit, but when I chart through Streamlit, it appears Streamlit is reconfiguring the axis for display.

Link to now-open github issue for tracking: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/4269#issue-1099607468

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without seeing the code you're running, it's difficult to guess what the problem might be or how to solve it.

Comment: @jakevdp added example. thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: @jakevdp It's a [streamlit](https://streamlit.io) issue. When I save my original chart to html directly, dates are displayed at 270degrees and no skips. when I use streamlit to display chart. dates are horizontal and I can't get all dates to display.

Answer (score 1):

The dates that are showing up in your example are the only ones in `x_vals` that are actually contained in your dataframe. You can see this by doing:

```
[x for x in x_vals if pd.to_datetime(x) in df['x'].to_numpy()]
```

```
['Jan 08, 2021',
 'Jan 11, 2021',
 'Jan 21, 2021',
 'Jan 29, 2021',
 'Feb 01, 2021',
 'Feb 11, 2021',
 'Feb 19, 2021',
 'Feb 22, 2021']
```

This is the expected outcome for ordinals since Altair will not create labels for that do not exist in the data (which is why you can use it to skip weekend dates).

The reason you are seeing the labeled rotated is because you must have used `axis=alt.Axis(values=x_vals, labelAngle=270)` or similar even if you didn't include it in your example code above. If you don't, some of the labels will be omitted since they would otherwise overlap as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the input. I don't think this is my solution, though. When I print `x_vals` to my console, I get: `['Jan 8, 2021', 'Jan 11, 2021', 'Jan 16, 2021', 'Jan 21, 2021', 'Jan 24, 2021', 'Jan 29, 2021', 'Feb 1, 2021', 'Feb 6, 2021', 'Feb 11, 2021', 'Feb 14, 2021', 'Feb 19, 2021', 'Feb 22, 2021', 'Feb 27, 2021']` - which is what I would expect on the x-axis.

Also, I don't have a `labelAngle` in my code. My thought is multiple encodings in the `alt.layer(...)`. I added a sreenshot of production code for reference.

Comment: @smgeneralist Yes that is the full x_vals list, but not all of those values are in the dataframe you included as an example in your question. By default, Altair will drop the values in X_vals that do not exist in the dataframe, which is why not all of them showed up in your example. It sounds like you have a different situation in your actual code, but it will be hard to help unless you can create a smaller example that reproduces the issue.